# Continue button and icons are hidden for my stepper flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, stepper

The issue is that progress icons and continue button are hidden in my stepper (cancel button is visible). So when i click on the place where "continue" button should exists (next to Cancel button) the "continue" event is happening and its correct.
The strange thing is that when i use the same code in a new test project, i can see both buttons and icons. Maybe its related to my sidebar but i am not sure.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:taamin/bloc/navigation_bloc/navigation_bloc.dart';

class MyOrdersPage extends StatefulWidget with NavigationStates{

  @override
  _MyOrdersPageState createState() => _MyOrdersPageState();
}

class _MyOrdersPageState extends State<MyOrdersPage> {
  List<Step> steps = [
    Step(
      title: const Text('New Account'),
      isActive: true,
      state: StepState.complete,
      content: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email Address'),
          ),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Step(
      title: const Text('Address'),
      isActive: true,
      state: StepState.editing,
      content: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Home Address'),
          ),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Postcode'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Step(
      state: StepState.error,
      title: const Text('Avatar'),
      subtitle: const Text("Error!"),
      content: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ];

  StepperType stepperType = StepperType.vertical;

  int currentStep = 0;
  bool complete = false;

  next() {
    currentStep + 1 != steps.length
        ? goTo(currentStep + 1)
        : setState(() => complete = true);
  }

  cancel() {
    if (currentStep > 0) {
      goTo(currentStep - 1);
    }
  }

  goTo(int step) {
    setState(() => currentStep = step);
  }

  switchStepType() {
    setState(() => stepperType == StepperType.horizontal
        ? stepperType = StepperType.vertical
        : stepperType = StepperType.horizontal);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Assurance Véhicule'),
        ),
        body: Column(children: <Widget>[
        complete ? Expanded(
        child: Center(
        child: AlertDialog(
        title: new Text("Profile Created"),
      content: new Text(
        "Tada!",
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        new FlatButton(
          child: new Text("Close"),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() => complete = false);
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
    ),
    )
          : Expanded(
            child: Stepper(
              steps: steps,
              type: stepperType,
              currentStep: currentStep,
              onStepContinue: next,
              onStepTapped: (step) => goTo(step),
              onStepCancel: cancel,
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.list),
        onPressed: switchStepType,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here is the code of my sidebar menu:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:taamin/bloc/navigation_bloc/navigation_bloc.dart';
import 'package:taamin/sidebar/menu_item.dart';

class SideBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SideBarState createState() => _SideBarState();
}

class _SideBarState extends State<SideBar>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin<SideBar> {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  StreamController<bool> isSidebarOpenedStreamController;
  Stream<bool> isSidebarOpenedStream;
  StreamSink<bool> isSidebarOpenedSink;
  final _animationDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 500);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: _animationDuration);
    isSidebarOpenedStreamController = PublishSubject<bool>();
    isSidebarOpenedStream = isSidebarOpenedStreamController.stream;
    isSidebarOpenedSink = isSidebarOpenedStreamController.sink;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    isSidebarOpenedStreamController.close();
    isSidebarOpenedSink.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void onIconPressed() {
    final animationStatus = _animationController.status;
    final isAnimationCompleted = animationStatus == AnimationStatus.completed;
    //completed means sidebar is open
    if (isAnimationCompleted) {
      isSidebarOpenedSink.add(false);
      _animationController.reverse();
    } else {
      isSidebarOpenedSink.add(true);
      _animationController.forward();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return StreamBuilder<bool>(
      initialData: false,
      stream: isSidebarOpenedStream,
      builder: (context, isSideBarOpenedAsync) {
        return AnimatedPositioned(
          duration: _animationDuration,
          top: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          left: isSideBarOpenedAsync.data ? 0 : -screenWidth,
          right: isSideBarOpenedAsync.data ? 0 : screenWidth - 30,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  color: const Color(0xFF262AAA),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 100,
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                          "Yassine",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 30,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                        ),
                        subtitle: Text(
                          "firstname.name@gmail.com",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xFF1BB5FD),
                            fontSize: 15,
                          ),
                        ),
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.perm_identity,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          radius: 40,
                        ),

                      ),
                      Divider(
                        height: 64,
                        thickness: 0.5,
                        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),
                        indent: 32,
                        endIndent: 32,
                      ),
                      MenuItem(
                        icon: Icons.home,
                        title: "Home",
                        onTap: () {
                          onIconPressed();
                          BlocProvider.of<NavigationBloc>(context).add(NavigationEvents.HomePageClickedEvent);
                        },
                      ),
                      MenuItem(
                        icon: Icons.person,
                        title: "My Accounts",
                        onTap: () {
                          onIconPressed();
                          BlocProvider.of<NavigationBloc>(context).add(NavigationEvents.MyAccountClickedEvent);
                        },
                      ),
                      MenuItem(
                        icon: Icons.directions_car,
                        title: "Assurance Véhicule",
                        onTap: () {
                          onIconPressed();
                          BlocProvider.of<NavigationBloc>(context).add(NavigationEvents.MyOrdersClickedEvent);
                        },
                      ),
                      MenuItem(
                        icon: Icons.card_giftcard,
                        title: "Wishlist",
                      ),
                      Divider(
                        height: 64,
                        thickness: 0.5,
                        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),
                        indent: 32,
                        endIndent: 32,
                      ),
                      MenuItem(
                        icon: Icons.settings,
                        title: "Settings",
                      ),
                      MenuItem(
                        icon: Icons.exit_to_app,
                        title: "Logout",
                          onTap: () {
                            onIconPressed();
                            exit(0);
                          }
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment(0, -0.9),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    onIconPressed();
                  },
                  child: ClipPath(
                    clipper: CustomMenuClipper(),
                    child: Container(
                      width: 35,
                      height: 110,
                      color: Color(0xFF262AAA),
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: AnimatedIcon(
                        progress: _animationController.view,
                        icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
                        color: Color(0xFF1BB5FD),
                        size: 25,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class CustomMenuClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.white;

    final width = size.width;
    final height = size.height;

    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, 8, 10, 16);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(width - 1, height / 2 - 20, width, height / 2);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(width + 1, height / 2 + 20, 10, height - 16);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, height - 8, 0, height);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add controlsBuilder inside stepper

```
controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
          {VoidCallback onStepContinue, VoidCallback onStepCancel}) {
        return Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: onStepContinue,
              child: const Text('Continue',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              color: Colors.redAccent,
            ),
            new Padding(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: onStepCancel,
              child: const Text(
                'Cancel',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
```